# Wrong databinding to tag id making Bootstrap nav tabs fail

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, data-binding, tabs

I am using the nav-tab class in bootstrap but I have these tabs as content to an accordion's panel body. I'm using Ng-repeat to fill in the number of tabs and the content of the tags.

```
<div class="panel-body">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                    <li ng-repeat="sub in All | unique:'onderwerpen'"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#{{sub.onderwerpen}}">{{sub.onderwerpen}}</a></li>
                                </ul>

                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div id="{{sub.onderwerpen}}" class="tab-pane fade active">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Jaar</th>
                                                    <th>Waarde</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>John</td>
                                                    <td>Doe</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

this is the code for the nav-tabs, but I think the id's I variably assign using the `{{sub.onderwerpen}}`isn't appointing correctly but I don't know what's wrong. 
I don't know if this is relevant but the `sub.onderwerpen` only gives back strings that contain spaces, would this be the issue? if so, how can I fix this?
Before answering, I am not able to use `{{$index}}` as a parameter to bind to id's because I used that in the parent panel.

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-repeat` directive creates new child scope and assigns `sub` variable in this scope.

`<div class="tab-content">` is in the parent scope relatively to scope which contains `sub` variable so it can't see it.

You need another `ng-repeat` inside your `tab-content` div.

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-repeat="sub in All | unique:'onderwerpen'">
      <a data-toggle="tab" ng-href="#{{sub.onderwerpen}}">{{sub.onderwerpen}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div ng-repeat="sub in All | unique:'onderwerpen'" id="{{sub.onderwerpen}}" class="tab-pane fade">
      <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Jaar</th>
            <th>Waarde</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also please use [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) when your link contains variable.

Also note that if `sub.onderwerpen` is used as `id` of DOM element then it

- Must contain at least one character
- Must not contain any space characters
- In HTML, all values are case-insensitive

Comment: oh ofcourse !!! I'l l'll try that and let you know if it works. Also thanks for the ng-href. never heard of this before. but could I use data-target instead aswell ?

Comment: I don't know what is `data-target`. I think it is some specific to `bootstrap`.

Comment: Also please see my edit about html `id` attribute and it's restrictions.

Comment: yes indeed it's bootstrap specific. I will certainly check it out ;) thanks

Comment: I understand the fact that the `id` may not contain spaces, but I'm using angular databinding to give these tags a unique `id`, but the values that are binded to these `id`'s contain spaces in their value, how would you suggest I could fix that?

Comment: You can just replace all spaces in them by some character which they doesn't contain already (to preserve uniqueness). For example `idWithSpaces.replace(/\s/g, '-')`. You can make angular filter to do it inline like `id="{{sub.onderwerpen | replaceSpaces}}"`. But it potentially can violate the uniqueness if some of id already contains this character. (`a-b` and `a b` will both become `a-b`). I recommend add some new generated `id` field for this. It can be a counter with prefix or [uuid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript).